# Jquery Pop-Up for Error Messages?

Tags: jquery

May be stupid Q for you but, I am trying to improve my jquery knowledge. I am showing error messages in alert box. Is there any standard API available to make programmers life simple. 
I did search but did not find it..

I knew, we can do this by using css and html. but, I am looking for jquery API. So, Instead of writing code in css, we can simply use API.

If you have any suggestions, I am very happy to try as per your suggestions.
would be grateful for help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might look at jqueryui. That projects provides you with modal dialogs that should do what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

From the jqueryui site:

> A call to $(foo).dialog() will initialize a dialog instance and will
>   auto-open the dialog by default. If you want to reuse a dialog, the
>   easiest way is to disable the "auto-open" option with: $(foo).dialog({
>   autoOpen: false }) and open it with $(foo).dialog('open'). To close
>   it, use $(foo).dialog('close')

Answer (score 3):

[**working demo click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ptJBK/1/)

This might help rest I can see that @jos has given a API link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

**code for dialog**

```
function showDialog() {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            },
            'No': function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
};

$('input').click(function(){
    showDialog();
});
​
```

Comment: @Vicky it aint link I made a demo for you :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery-confirm library is a good choice. Look at https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/
May be used not only for confirm but also as popup, alert and so on.